# How can I combine two condition together?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe such as:

```
EXCLUDE    WARNSIGN_DTL    EVENT_DTL    EVENT_DTL_2

1_1    The thing happened on 2021...    according to this, this people did bla bla on 2021...    It happened on 2021....
1_2    similar thing happened on 2012...    that was happened on 2012...
...
1_1    Sam did on 2012...    that was happened on 2012...    it hasn't made sense till 2012...
```

Note: I simplified the original code in this

I made a code such as:

```
df_check = df[['EXCLUDE','WARNSIGN_DTL','EVENT_DTL','EVENT_DTL_2']]
df_check.EXCLUDE!=1_1 & df_check.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('2021|2012', na=False))
```

but I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 82.1 GiB for an array with shape (104959, 104959) and data type float64
```

Comment: Sorry that I didn't attach all of the error message, couldn't post all of it here since it's too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first condition add `()` and for second add [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) if need test if all `True`s per rows or
[`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) if test at least one `True` per row:

```
mask = (df_check.EXCLUDE!='1_1') & 
        df_check.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('2021|2012', na=False).all(axis=1))
```

---

```
mask = (df_check.EXCLUDE!='1_1') & 
        df_check.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('2021|2012', na=False).any(axis=1))
```

Comment: Oh I forgot ' ' on EXCLUDE column